Compile error in VBA 'named argument not found'
I am getting error while saving an Excel file from XSLM to XLSX. Now I am getting an error while using file format.
Sub SaveExsistingWorkbook()

Dim Fldr As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Report Tracker\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


According to the documentation the parameter FileFormat is not available for the SaveCopyAs method. You could try to include the file extension in the path/file name.

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/savecopyas-and-change-file-format.603498/
